# Why does "If Value is Nothing" throw "Object Required (Error 424)"

Tags: vba, if-statement

The following code throws `Object Required (Error 424)` at the if statement comparing with `Nothing` independent of the value given. Why?

```
Public Function SqlizeCellValue(ByVal Value As Variant) As Variant
    If Value Is Nothing Then
        SqlizeCellValue = Nothing
    ElseIf Value = Null Then
        SqlizeCellValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = "" Then
        SqlizeCellValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = "0" Then
        SqlizeCellValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = "---" Then
        SqlizeCellValue = Null
    ElseIf LCase(Value) = "n.c." Then
        SqlizeCellValue = Null
    Else
        SqlizeCellValue = Value
    End If
End Function
Public Sub TestSqlizeCellValue()
    Debug.Assert SqlizeCellValue("") Is Null
    Debug.Assert SqlizeCellValue("0") Is Null
    Debug.Assert SqlizeCellValue("---") Is Null
    Debug.Assert SqlizeCellValue(Nothing) Is Nothing
    Debug.Assert SqlizeCellValue(Null) Is Null
End Sub
```

Comment: Because `Value` is a `Variant` and only an `Object` can be set to `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Could you provide this as an answer please, so I can mark it as accepted/ correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Value` in your function definition is set to type `Variant` and only an `Object` can be `Set` to `Nothing`

Comment: I don't think this is true. `Variant` can be set to anything, including objects and nothings, but the `is` operator throws a type error, when it's not either an object or `Nothing`.